# Why is in Java wrong constructor called?

Tags: java, constructor

This a class with 2 constructors:

```
public class Product {
private String name;
private boolean[] r;
private boolean[] i;

public Product(String name, boolean[] r, boolean[] i) {
    this.name = name;
    this.r = r;
    this.i = i;
}
public Product Product(String name, String r, String i){
    this.name= name;
    this.r= BooleanStringHelper.parse(r,'1');
    this.i= BooleanStringHelper.parse(i, '1');
    return this;
} }
```

if I call in the main() the following code:

```
Product p = new Product("MyProduct", "000001111100", "111100000011");
```

then the first constructor is called, but I would like to call the second constructor

```
public Product Product(String name, String r, String i)
```

Why is wrong constructor called?

Comment: You are wrong. Try adding print statements.

Comment: Because the second method isn't a constructor. Constructors don't have return types

Comment: The code you show (that attempts to create a new Product object) should not even compile, nevermind run.  There is no constructor available that matches your expression.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is not a constructor, it's a method.

Comment: Might add "Remove return type `Product` and `return this;`."